# Provide Application Insights Agent path to Azure Functions when deployed via Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

We deploy Azure Function using the docker image. The application insights agent is manually provided as specified here: [Java - Azure Application Insights Dynamic Tracing not working with docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085054/java-azure-application-insights-dynamic-tracing-not-working-with-docker-images/71085468#71085468)

This works fine when deployed via `mvn azure-functions:deploy`. But doesn't work when deployed using azure dev-ops. These are the steps:

1. We create the docker image and publish it to ACR
2. We then provide the docker image to the below task:

Here is the ADO task

```
- task: AzureFunctionAppContainer@1
  displayName: 'Azure Function App on Container Deploy: $(orchestratorfunctionappName)'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.environments.serviceConnectionId }}'
    appName: appName
    imageName: 'appImage'
```

There is no clear documentation to provide the `JAVA_OPTS` path

Comment: inside the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085054/java-azure-application-insights-dynamic-tracing-not-working-with-docker-images/71085468#71085468) given by you JAVA_OPTS is set in the pom.xml file.

Comment: I dont think JAVA_OPTS is read when deployed from ADO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below worked for me:

```
- task: AzureFunctionAppContainer@1
  displayName: 'Azure Function App on Container Deploy: $(orchestratorfunctionappName)'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.environments.serviceConnectionId }}'
    appName: appName
    imageName: 'appImage'
    appSettings: '-JAVA_OPTS "-javaagent:/home/site/wwwroot/applicationinsights-agent.jar"'
```

The agent needs to exist at that path on the image. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71085054/java-azure-application-insights-dynamic-tracing-not-working-with-docker-images/71085468#71085468))